# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (148584, 1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I know there are some questions similar to one that I'm asking but I couldn't make fit any of them into my situation. I'm having an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (148584, 1)
```

Here is my test code:

```
model = load_model('lstm_model.hdf5')
data = np.fromfile('jelik_20181104_3211')
model.predict(data)
```

I couldn't handle how to change its format so that it can fit into the model, if that's the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check `model.summary()`, and feed an array that is compatible with the output layer.

Comment: I'm trying to classifier 7 different hand action, so I guess the output layer is
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param # 
dense_1 (Dense)        (None, 7)                      7175  
According to you, do I need to give a format to my data variable that will be seperated into some parts that consist of 7 elements?

Comment: Are the input to your model video frames?